# Formal way to say you bumped into someone

Tags: verbs

What is a formal way to say you bumped into someone? I'm referring to an unplanned encounter with someone you know.

Can you say "Yesterday I met John at the doctor" if you didn't plan to meet him?

Comment: You can, Jose, but it would be ambiguous. 'Meet' can have either sense: 'bump into' / 'meet up with as arranged'. "I encountered John at the doctors" is extremely formal (and nobody would say it). '... came across' is semi-formal but connotes a comment that there was something almost suspicious about John's being there or that it had been a long time since you'd seen him(!). '... saw' defaults to the 'by chance rather than design' sense here, but can have the other sense. It doesn't entail conversation, either ( " ... but he didn't see me.")

Comment: _Ran into_ is less colloquial than _bumped into_, but still hardly formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Encountered** is formal and fits. But you need to add an adjective to indicate that the meeting was unexpected:

> “Yesterday I *unexpectedly* encountered John…”

or

> “Yesterday, *by chance*, I encountered John…”

As a simpler alternative to the word, *encounter*, you could just use **met**, e.g.

> “Yesterday, by chance, I *met* John…”

If you want a single word (albeit with a preposition), you could use the verb, *chance*:

> “Yesterday I **chanced** *into* John…”

or with another verb:

> “Yesterday I **chanced** *to meet* John…”

This is not informal, and although derived from a noun, is of some antiquity. The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/30419?rskey=BBnsUB&result=2#eid) gives example from the sixteenth century, e.g.

> “**Chaunsynge** into the company of them”

Although it describes it as “somewhat archaic”, the verb chance is in the (US) [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chanced) dictionary:

> to come or light by chance
>
> *they **chanced** upon a remote inn*

Comment: These both sound quite awkward for US English.

Comment: @aparente001 — Agreed. Partly because they are formal. I have modified my answer to give an example with a less awkward word order for the "by chance" example, and suggested the alternative of the more common, "met", to "encountered". I have also given a US dictionary example of the usage of the verb, "chance".

Comment: Sorry, David, none of the suggestions in your revised post would make a listener comfortable in the US.  One sounds more stilted than the next, to my ear.  Maybe it's the Old World-New World difference.

Comment: @aparente001 — Depends on your audience. Harvard graduation?  And also whether the poster really means say rather than write. Incidentally, I think your suggestion of “happen” is as good as “chance”.